# Estimating the range of values of x for which the absolute error in the approximation of $\cos[x]$ is accurate to within 0.08

Tags: approximation

The approximation is for $\cos[x] \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{24}$. I've tried a combination of many different things, but can't figure it out. My error always ends up as {0.00136436}. Any help would be great, I'm really wracking my brain over this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(rng = Reduce[{Abs[Cos[x] - (1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24)] < 2/25, 
    0 <= x < 2 Pi}, x])
```

[image]

```
rng[[-1]] // N

(* 1.98824 *)

Abs[Cos[x] - (1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24)] /. x -> 2.

(* 0.0828135 *)

Plot[{Abs[Cos[x] - (1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24)], 2/25}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or due to symmetry,

```
(rng = Reduce[{Abs[Cos[x] - (1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24)] < 2/25, 
  -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi}, x])
```

[image]